# Client stuck when trying to connect via TCP/IP

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am new with socket programming and I have been following this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/

But it is only to use it in the local machine and my goal is to connect an embedded system with my computer (the computer is the server and the embedded system is the client).

To achieve the connection between the two systems, I have changed the servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr part of the client.c code, introducing the IP of the server in that line.

My server code (it gets compiled via gcc in the computer):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h> // read(), write(), close()
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr

// Function designed for chat between client and server.
void func(int connfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    // infinite loop for chat
    for (;;) {
        bzero(buff, MAX);

        // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
        read(connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        // print buffer which contains the client contents
        printf("From client: %s\t To client : ", buff);
        bzero(buff, MAX);
        n = 0;
        // copy server message in the buffer
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;

        // and send that buffer to client
        write(connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));

        // if msg contains "Exit" then server exit and chat ended.
        if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0) {
            printf("Server Exit...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Driver function
int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd, len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");

    // Now server is ready to listen and verification
    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n");
    len = sizeof(cli);

    // Accept the data packet from client and verification
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);
    if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("server accept the client...\n");

    // Function for chatting between client and server
    func(connfd);

    // After chatting close the socket
    close(sockfd);
}
```

My client code (it gets compiled via gcc in the embedded system)

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> // inet_addr()
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h> // bzero()
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h> // read(), write(), close()
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr
void func(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    for (;;) {
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        printf("Enter the string : ");
        n = 0;
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        printf("From Server : %s", buff);
        if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0) {
            printf("Client Exit...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.182.128");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // connect the client socket to server socket
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))
        != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");

    // function for chat
    func(sockfd);

    // close the socket
    close(sockfd);
}
```

The issue comes when I execute the client executable in the embedded system (after executing the server executable in the computer), as it gets stuck when trying to connect:

root@imx8mq-var-dart:~# ./client

Socket successfully created..

(infinitely here)

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: As I understand, the client is stuck waiting for the connection to be established. Are you sure that the communication between client and server is working?

Comment: Yes, the client gets stuck in the connect part. As far as I know, the communication between the client and the server it's possible (for example, I can send files from the computer to the embedded system via scp command)

Comment: I get the same behaviour on normal desktop Linux if I try to connect to a machine on a different subnet that doesn't exist. Have you definitely got the IP address of the server right? Can you ping it from your client machine?

Comment: The code looks okay. I frequently use a tool called Wireshark to debug similar issues - you can see the individual packets your computer is sending and receiving. You might see that the computer is sending a packet to try to connect (TCP SYN) and not getting any reply

Comment: I have been pinging and I realized that I can ping from the PC to the embedded system BUT I cannot do it the other way. Although this is not a complete solution (as I am still unable to use the PC as the server), for my application I can use the embedded system as the server so now I can make a connection between the two systems. Thanks for the replies!